# Why does calling Add throw an exception in a collection cast to ICollection<T>?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am not too sure I understand what OOP principle prevents me from using methods from a type B that I cast a type A to.

Specific example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] week = new string[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "wednesday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
        ICollection<string> coll = (ICollection<string>)week;
        coll.Add("SlaveDay"); // this throws an error

        ICollection<string> coll2 = new List<string>() { "Monday", "Tuesday", "wednesday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };
        coll2.Add("SlaveDay"); // this works

    }
}
```

Of course, arrays are fixed size, so I understand why week (being of type `string[]` or array of strings) cannot be added any new elements.
However, after I explicitly cast it to an `ICollection<string>` (which by the way is different than `IReadableCollection<string>`) I would have expected adding a new element to work.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx#Remarks

I found out from here
that the array class explicitly implements `IList.Add(Object)`  and **Calling this method always throws a NotSupportedException exception.**

Is this the explanation of why the first call throws an error?

And if so, can it be assumed that the `Add` is a method in the `Array` class that overrides the `Add` method from `IList`? (override keyword instead of new)
e.g. If it was a new method instead of overriding, that line wouldn't have thrown an error, yes?

Secondly, is this type of situations the reason why: in what is expected to be a normally modifiable collection `ICollection<T>` (as opposed to `IReadableCollection<T>`), we have a property called `IsReadOnly`?

Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: How can you expect that to work? What would it do? Casting doesn't change anything.  It's still an array; you're just looking at it differently.

Comment: Agreed with SLaks. I think you're confusing a Conversion and a Cast, whereas a Conversion typically copies from one type to another.

Comment: You're conflating casting and converting, no doubt aided by the fact that some casts also perform conversions. It's unfortunate. But the simple fact is that no conversion is occurring here, which is why Add fails.

Comment: Anthony Pegram, very interesting, some casts also perform conversions? Would you elaborate on that please? Thank you all!

Comment: @hhdr103 Custom conversions from one class to another use the familiar "(Cast)" syntax. Conversions of primitives do the same (`int x = (int)some decimal;`).  Those are the exceptions, of course, and not the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting something doesn't magically change it to have all of the methods of that something. An array is still an array; casting is usually for when you want to read something, not modify it.  It'd be undesirable from a maintainability/legibility standpoint anyway. If you want a mutable collection, this is what you're probably looking for:

```
    string[] week = new string[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "wednesday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
    var coll = week.ToList();
    coll.Add("SlaveDay");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the NotSupportedException is probably the exception you'll get by calling the Add method in your ICollection casted from an array.

> can it be assumed that the Add is a method in the Array class that overrides the Add method from IList?

The array class is not "overriding" the Add from IList because IList is an interface whereas Array is a class. Classes implements interfaces just to "comply" with the interface's contract.
In C# though (not sure about other languages) it is possible to [explicitly implement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) an interface method. By doing that, the implemented method will only be available if you hold a variable with the interface type, that is why you can only see the "Add" method when you cast the array to ICollection.
The array class probably has an one line implementation for the Add method throwing the `NotSupportException`.

> is this type of situations the reason why: in what is expected to be a normally modifiable collection ICollection (as opposed to IReadableCollection), we have a property called IsReadOnly?

The IList interface is quite old, I'm not sure what was the purpose of adding this property in there. If you intend to have a class implementing IList that can't be changed I would suggest against it. There is a concept called *interface segregation principle* (the I in SOLID), so if you need to implement a collection that is read-only you should ideally implement an interface that has no methods for adding new items.
One good usage for this `IsReadOnly` is to indicate a state in your implementation of `IList`, so based on something, like the amount of items in the list, you could indicate that your list is in a read-only state.